# Kafka streams timing out with Timeout of 300000ms expired before the position for partition eventlog-1 could be determined

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

Hi Kafka users Community

I am having an issue with my kafka stream setup. Things were working good for more than 8 months, from few days I am seeing issues, seeing a timeout in log like

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: 
Timeout of 300000ms expired before the position for partition eventlog-1 could be determined
```

There is one case where there is fix in the updated Kafka-stream library(3.4.1) I updated that, there are still places where this exception is thrown and the thread stops. I am using replace thread in case of uncaught exception, it gets into rebalances and things don't settle.

A restart to streams application, it runs for few minutes and again gets into same exception this time it might be when calculating position for another topic partition.

These are not bad partitions as I see when it works, the consumer log does not lag for these partitions.

Other information:

1. Having data store on a persistent volume
2. Running one process with 3 threads. Even 1 thread didn't help, thought might remove any unknown contention.
3. Broker logs does not show any errors.
4. Some important configuration value

```
max.poll.interval.ms 300000
session.timeout.ms 45000
heartbeat.interval.ms 3000
default.api.timeout.ms 60000
max.poll.records 1000
linger.ms 100
batch.size 16384
request.timeout.ms 500
delivery.timeout.ms 120000
retries 2147483647
retry.backoff.ms 100
```

Any idea why is calculating position taking infinite time? I am unable to progress.

Asking the community for any possible solution.

There are no network issues as the streams applications and broker are co-located and there were no changes in infra since long time.

Tried increasing the default.api.timeout.ms which is triggered here, to a higher value, but that did not help.
Even increasing max.poll.interval.ms and session.timeout.ms and decreasing max.poll.records also did not help.

The process times aren't big, I am confident on this because consumer lag comes to order of <100 in just couple of minutes.. and records being in order of 100 thousand when I am starting..